# How to run playwright asynchronously in Scrapy Python?

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright

My example code works synchronously without mistakes. It parses all the start urls and prints needed text to the output.

How to make this code work asynchronously?
(I need to run playwright calling the function call_playwright(), not yielding)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


class ToscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://example.com/?1',
        'https://example.com/?2',
        'https://example.com/?3',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        link = response.url
        self.call_playwright(link)

    
    def call_playwright(self, url):
        with sync_playwright() as playwright:
            browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
            page = browser.new_page()
            page.goto(url)
            page.wait_for_selector('h1', timeout=5000)
            tag = page.locator('h1')
            print(tag.inner_text())
            browser.close()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(ToscrapeSpider)
    process.start()
```

This is my version of asynchronous use of playwright:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


class ToscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://example.com/?1',
        'https://example.com/?2',
        'https://example.com/?3',
    ]


    async def parse(self, response):
        link = response.url
        await self.call_playwright(link)

    
    async def call_playwright(self, url):
        async with async_playwright() as playwright:
            browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
            page = await browser.new_page()
            await page.goto(url)
            await page.wait_for_selector('h1', timeout=5000)
            tag = page.locator('h1')
            print(tag.inner_text())
            await browser.close()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(ToscrapeSpider)
    process.start()
```

When I try to run it I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1697, in _inlineCallbacks   
    result = context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "h:\spiders\getprices.py", line 21, in parse
    await self.call_playwright(link)
  File "h:\spiders\getprices.py", line 25, in call_playwright
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\async_api\_context_manager.py", line 31, in __aenter__
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

Could you please help me with this? Python 3.10.7, Scrapy 2.8.0, Playwright 1.34.0

Answer (score 0):

The type of pattern that i have used for asyncio looks like this:

```py
async def main():
    ''' some async code '''

    return



if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```